# How to use Motorola H390 Bluetooth Headset as a sound device on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, audio, bluetooth, headset

I've just bought a Motorola H390 Bluetooth Headset. I can use it with my smartphone (Nokia 5800 XM) and also with Skype on my laptop.

Is it possible to use it as a headphone to listen to all sounds on my laptop?

For example: movies, Winamp etc?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to do it by using software called [Bluesoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/).

After adding my headset via Bluesoleil,I went to Control Panel > Devices & Printers > Set Bluetooth Headset as default for sound devices

Answer (score 0):

The stock Windows Bluetooth stack does not support audio profiles as an audio target. Acquire and install the Bluetooth stack provided by the dongle manufacturer.